# Spring Data MongoDB prevent persisting certain fields

Tags: mongodb, persistence, spring-data

I am using Spring Data for MongoDB to persist my domain objects. I was wondering if there is a way (perhaps with an Annotation?) to prevent Spring Data from persisting certain fields into MongoDB?

Does someone know how to do that or do I have to write my own Mapper?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In this case use the `@Transient` annotation for the field you need to ignore.

Look more over here - [Transient](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/annotation/Transient.html)

Answer (score 3):

In case you are looking for the actual package like I was, this one will work:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient;
```

Which is from the [Spring framework API](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/annotation/Transient.html) documentation.

But this one, which is a [JPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API) annotation, will not work for Spring Data's MongoDB:

```
import javax.persistence.Transient;
```

Which is part of the [Java Persistence API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html).